# Overlay with opacity setting using Sharp

Tags: javascript, sharp

I'd like to take one image and composite it on top of another image.

This works well for that purpose:

```
overlayImg = await Sharp(sourceImage.Body)
            .composite([{ 
                input: './lambdas/processNewImage/logos/white.png', 
                gravity: 'southeast',
                
            }])
            .toFormat('jpeg').toBuffer();
```

I also have a variable - 1-100 that is supposed to be the opacity of the watermark.  Sometimes I want it full solid At 100% opacity, others 70% and others 30%...etc.  Because I need this to be variable, I cannot just change the opacity of the watermark image.

I cannot figure out how to change the opacity of a composited image in Sharp.

Can any one give a quick example?

Answer (score 4):

Found this in another thread where you overlay with a raw pixel buffer containing tiled, semi-transparent pixel value. 128 means 50% opacity where valid values are 0-255.
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/554

```
overlayImg = await Sharp(sourceImage.Body)
  .composite([
    { 
      input: './lambdas/processNewImage/logos/white.png', 
      gravity: 'southeast',  
    },
    {
      input: Buffer.from([0,0,0,128]),
      raw: {
        width: 1,
        height: 1,
        channels: 4,
      },
      tile: true,
      blend: 'dest-in',
    }
  ])
  .toFormat('jpeg').toBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharp can change the alpha channel (opacity) of an image. https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-channel#ensurealpha

```js
sharp(current_path + 'logo.png')
  .ensureAlpha(0.5) // 50% opacity 
  .toBuffer()
  .then(transparent_logo=>{

      sharp(current_path + 'photo.png')
             .composite([{input: transparent_logo }])
             .toFile(current_path + 'output.png');
  })
```

Comment: This approach would work with JPG images but not PNG. `ensureAlpha` _ensures_ an alpha channel. If the image already has an alpha channel then nothing will happen.